requesting tags to be made
I was wondering if it would be a good idea to have Meta tag named tag-request where you can request tags to be added and if it gets enough community votes then it becomes an official tag if there is votes to not make it an official tag then it will be blacklisted from becoming a tag, example someone suggests EndeavourOS because it's a arch based distro and has some questions that use the arch tag a similar thing that stack overflow does is burninate-request which requests tags to be removed

I'd you really feel a tag is missing, sure, you can ask for one here. There's nothing more to it than just posting a question.

@terdon what about this https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7213/policy-on-creation-of-distribution-tags-for-derivatives

I don't understand what you mean. What about that post?  That is a question discussing when a specific category of tag should be created. I said that if you feel a tag is needed and want to request it, all you need to do is ask a question here.

@terdon I may be mistaken, but I think the idea was to first introduce a 'tag-request' tag here on meta with which to tag the question.

Is that what you mean @killertofus? Are you asking for a new meta tag?

@terdon yes, that is what I am asking for

Oh. Then please edit and clarify because it is not at all clear from your question. And I don't quite understand what you describe about SO either. A burninate request is to remove tags, not add them.

@terdon edited.

Frankly, I don't really see much use to it. Very many users can create tags, it only takes 300 reputation. It is also not a particularly common occurrence, so I don't really see much benefit in having a meta tag tag-request. Our Meta isn't very active at all, so the tag wouldn't really help make the question visible.
I don't have anything against such a tag either, I just don't really think it is needed. And since any user with 300 rep can create tags, the fact that it hasn't been created does suggest there isn't much of a demand. We already have a few meta tags about tags, and given how rarely they are used, I think the existing tags can be used for most things related to tagging.

That said, if anyone wants to, they can create it and we will see if it ends up being used.
